# How to insert ® value in database

Tags: database

I am inserting users from drupal6 to drupal7 using a custom script. I am using db_insert function.
In one of the D6 entry I am getting ® mark in a field and because  of this that particular value become blank in D7 database.
D6:  imatter®    ->   D7:

Anyone has any idea about how to insert this value in database?

Collation is same in both database: utf8_general_ci
And in phpmyadmin its look like same as above, means no html code for ®

Comment: what is your query statement?

Answer (score 0):

In the case that your insertion script is not capable of handling UTF-8 encoding (it sounds like this is the case), you can get around this by inserting this character as 7-bit HTML entities (i.e. `&#174;` or `&reg;`) *provided* the field where it appears is going to be rendered as HTML (and not as plain text).  Just do a search and replace and replace all occurences of ® with `&#174;` in the source text file.

If this workaround doesn't work (because the field is supposed to be plain text, or for some other reason), you must do two things:

1. Make sure your file containing these characters is UTF-8 (*not* ISO-8859-1 or some other encoding incompatible with UTF-8).
2. Make sure your insertion script is capable of handling UTF-8 (`db_insert` is, but I don't know what other components you use).

Answer (score -1):

Try `utf8_encode` before store you variable

```
$username=$olduser.'®';
$newusername =  utf8_encode($username);
```

or Drupali method

```
$username=$olduser.'®';
$newusername =   drupal_convert_to_utf8($username,'utf-8');
```

Comment: @GisleHannemyr,tnx, I update my answer

Comment: Your first suggestion (call to PHP `utf8_encode`) will *only* work if the source file is in ISO-8859-1 encoding. Re: [utf8_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) Yes, it may work, or it may not, depending on the the source data format.  Your second suggestion (call Drupal API `drupal_convert_to_utf8`) is a no-op, and will not work here.